# SQL Server Multiple Counts in the same Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this but I've been struggling with this one...

Suppose I have an order table like so:

```
OrderId   OrderStatus   DriverId  TripId
-------   -----------   ------    ----
 1         Available     5         2
 2         Available     5         2
 3         Available     5         2
 4         Delivered     5         2
 5         Delivered     5         3
 6         Delivered     6         2
```

I want to group by each Driver and Trip with an extra column displaying the count of the OrderStatus when it is equal to 'Available'. So, for example

```
TotalOrderCountInTrip   DriverId   TripId  AvailableOrdersCount
---------------------   --------   ------  --------------------
 4                       5          2       3
 1                       6          2       0
```

I've gotten this far but I can't figure out how to add the AvailableOrdersCount column:

```
select count(*) TotalOrderCountInTrip, dos.DriverId, dos.TripId
from DriverOrderSet dos (nolock)
group by
   dos.DriverId,
   dos.TripId
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add as a column:

```
sum(case when OrderStatus = 'Available' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: SELECT 
        dos.DriverId, 
        dos.TripId, 
        COUNT(*) AS TotalOrderCountInTrip,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderStatus = 'Available' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AvailableOrdersCount
    FROM DriverOrderSet dos WITH (nolock)
    GROUP BY
        dos.DriverId,
        dos.TripId

Comment: Ahhh so simple when you know how :) Thank you. That did it!